# MDX : Combine two role playing dimension, with multi values

Tags: mdx

I'm working since few days on a MDX question and I dont see any issues...

Here is the context :

I have a fact table :

```
+----------+--------+-------------+------------+------------------+
| Line num | Amount |  Line Type  |    Date    | DateConfirmation |
+----------+--------+-------------+------------+------------------+
|        1 |    100 | Reservation | 01/01/2016 | 12/01/2016       |
|        2 |     50 | Reservation | 01/01/2016 | Empty            |
|        3 |     80 | Reservation | 20/12/2015 | 01/01/2016       |
|        4 |     30 | DirectSales | 01/01/2016 | 01/01/2016       |
+----------+--------+-------------+------------+------------------+
```

So in SSAS i have designed a cube with

- Amount measure
- Date dimension
- Date Confirmation dimension

Then 2 date dimensions are role playing dimensions

What I need is to combine, when analysis by Date, all the reservations plus the reservations that have been confirmed at the same date of currentMember.

So i've writted this MDX :

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Sales].[Type].[All].[Confirmed Reservations]
 AS NULL , 
VISIBLE = 1; 

Scope ( [Sales].[Type].[All].[Confirmed Reservations] ); 

    Scope(  MeasureGroupMeasures("Sales") , [Date].[Hierarchy].Members , [Date].[Date].Members
        , [Date Confirmation].[Hierarchy].[All] , [Date Confirmation].[Date].[All]  );   

        This =  ([Sales].[Type].&[Reservation], StrToMember("[Date Confirmation].[Hierarchy]." + Right(MemberToStr([Date].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember),  Len(MemberToStr([Date].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember)) - Len("[Date].[Hierarchy].") ) ), [Date].[Hierarchy].[All] );

    End Scope; 

End Scope;
```

The expected result, if I analyse the sales & reservations with the Date dimension at 01/01/2016 is

```
+------------------------+-----------+
| Reservation            | 150 (1+2) |
| DirectSales            | 30 (4)    |
| Confirmed Reservations | 80 (3)    |
+------------------------+-----------+
```

This works perfectly if I select in Excel only one date. But It produce very bad result when more than one date is select.

All your suggestions will be very helpfull for me !
Many thanks at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to tackle this in MDX I would suggest a simpler approach. If your current fact table query in the DSV is:

```
Select LineNum, Amount, LineType, Date, DateConfirmation
From YourFact
```

I would change it to:

```
Select LineNum, Amount, LineType, Date, DateConfirmation
From YourFact

UNION ALL

Select LineNum, Amount, 'Confirmed Reservations' as LineType, DateConfirmation as Date, DateConfirmation
From YourFact
WHERE DateConfirmation is not null
```

Then you shouldn't need any MDX.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I can't do that because it will duplicate all my "confirmed" lines.

Comment: @user3429139 please clarify how you handle confirmed reservations. If you filtered your report to January 2016 which categories should line num 1 show under? Both Reservation and Confirmed Reservations? Is there a grand total and would it count that $100 once or twice?

Comment: @user3429139 can you answer my question?